# jetty server is not shutting down ever after executing terminal command

Tags: java, jetty

following this tutorial:
https://github.com/xzer/run-jetty-run
i ran my jetty test method via command line and i am able to make calls on port 8080 however unfortunately i cannot now stop jetty on port 8080 stopping me from doing any more work. 
i am using

```
java -jar start.jar --stop STOP.PORT=8080 STOP.KEY=stopkey --stacktrace
```

any help please?

this is my build test method i ran 
gradle integrationTest

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest*'
    doFirst {
        jettyRun.contextPath = '/';
        jettyRun.httpPort = 8080    // Port for test
        jettyRun.daemon = true
        jettyRun.execute()
    }
    doLast {
        jettyStop.stopPort = 8091   // Port for stop signal
        jettyStop.stopKey = 'stopKey'
        jettyStop.execute()
    }
}
```

http://localhost:8080/hello
keeps printing hello world.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the main jetty with the STOP PORT and KEY too.

Otherwise the call to STOP jetty cannot do anything.